# Getting form error "is not a valid value for a primary key."

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have django model like below

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user_model(), related_name="user")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
    interest = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, null=True, blank=True)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/profile_photos/", null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(user_model(),null=True, blank=True,
                                       related_name="follower")
```

and i am using model form 
but when I try to save the form without giving interest and city values i get the following error in debugger. I re-created the database and still the same. Any ideas ??

```
ipdb> self.errors
{'city': [u'This field is required.'], 'interest': [u'"" is not a valid value for a primary key.']}
```

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: If you're getting a 'This field is required' error, then you're either a) setting the city field to `required=True` in your ModelField definition, or b) have a database schema that doesn't match the code above.  (But if you just re-created the db, then you should be good on the latter)  If you can show your form code, we'll be able to troubleshoot properly.

Comment: thanks, i totaaly forgot the required=True part

Comment: As above mentioned error might be coming up from the form, when you are defining form you might have added attribute 'required' that might be causing it. By any chance did you added the null=True, blank=True after running the migration?